# Перебор массива JSON и его последующая запись в документ

Tags: php, json

не могу сообразить как правильно перебрать массив.

Есть массив в формате JSON, как правильно его перебрать (для последующей записи в файл), интересуют значение **`id`**.

```
{"response": {
"count": 5,
"items": [{
"id": 456239196,
"album_id": 262864474,
"owner_id": -177279513,
"user_id": 100,
"sizes": [...],
"text": "",
"date": 1549408532
}, {
"id": 456239198,
"album_id": 262864474,
"owner_id": -177279513,
"user_id": 100,
"sizes": [...],
"text": "",
"date": 1549470093
}, {
"id": 456239200,
"album_id": 262864474,
"owner_id": -177279513,
"user_id": 100,
"sizes": [...],
"text": "",
"date": 1549470104
}, {
"id": 456239202,
"album_id": 262864474,
"owner_id": -177279513,
"user_id": 100,
"sizes": [...],
"text": "",
"date": 1549470117
}, {
"id": 456239204,
"album_id": 262864474,
"owner_id": -177279513,
"user_id": 100,
"sizes": [...],
"text": "",
"date": 1549470122
}]}}
```

Пример его получения:

```
$album_info = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://api.vk.com/method/photos.get?owner_id=-177279513&album_id={$album_id}&count=10000&access_token={$standalone_token}&v=5.92"));
```

Как перебирал...

```
foreach($album_info as $vs) {
    foreach($vs['items'] as $qs) {
        $result = 'photo'.$qs['owner_id'].'_'.$qs['id'];
        file_put_contents($config['album_1'], $result."\n", FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение:

```
$str = file_get_contents("https://api.vk.com/method/photos.get?owner_id=-177279513&album_id={$album_id}&count=1000&access_token={$standalone_token}&v=5.92");       
$album_info = json_decode($str, true);

foreach($album_info['response']['items'] as $qs) {
    $result = 'photo'.$qs['owner_id'].'_'.$qs['id'];
    file_put_contents($config['album_1'], $result."\n", FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = '{"response":{"count":5,"items":[{"id":456239196,"album_id":262864474,"owner_id":-177279513,"user_id":100,"text":"","date":1549408532},{"id":456239198,"album_id":262864474,"owner_id":-177279513,"user_id":100,"text":"","date":1549470093},{"id":456239200,"album_id":262864474,"owner_id":-177279513,"user_id":100,"text":"","date":1549470104},{"id":456239202,"album_id":262864474,"owner_id":-177279513,"user_id":100,"text":"","date":1549470117},{"id":456239204,"album_id":262864474,"owner_id":-177279513,"user_id":100,"text":"","date":1549470122}]}}';
$album_info = json_decode($str, true);

foreach($album_info['response']['items'] as $qs) {
    $result = 'photo'.$qs['owner_id'].'_'.$qs['id'];
    print $result."\n";
}
```

Comment: Благодарю, немного перестроил твой вариант. Спасибо что направил в верное русло =)